# HTML5でバイトデータをimgタグで表示したい

Tags: html5

HTML5で下記のように画像が表示できることを確認できたのですが、
byteデータをimgタグで表示することは可能でしょうか。

```
<img src="img/testicon.png"/>
```

javaのコントローラークラス

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView index(ModelAndView mav) {
    mav.setViewName("index");
    mav.addObject("iconInfo", アイコン情報);
    return mav;
}
```

アイコン情報にはデーターベースから取得したバイト配列（byte[] icon;）
を保持する情報クラス（Serializable）になります。

HTML5側で

```
${iconInfo.icon}
```

みたいな感じで指定できないだろうかと思うのですが…

Answer (score 4):

javaには詳しくないので具体的なコードを示せないのですが、base64エンコードした画像データを[data URI scheme](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/data_URIs)で`src`に指定することで、画像の埋め込みが可能です。

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,[base64エンコードした画像データ]" />
```

たとえばこんな感じです。

```html
<!-- URLで指定 -->
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/6CJiBQq.png" />
<!-- Data URIで埋め込み -->
<img src="data:image/png;base64,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" />
```

以下未確認ですので参考までに。

- [Java で Base64 エンコード/デコードを行う処理方法の選択について | WEB ARCH LABO](http://weblabo.oscasierra.net/java-base64-1/)

Answer (score 0):

FirefoxのJavascriptで

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", '画像のURI', true);
xhr.responseType = "blob";
xhr.onload = function() {
  if (xhr.status === 200) {
    var element = document.getElementById('イメージタグのID');
    if (element.src != null) URL.revokeObjectURL(element.src);
      element.src = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
      element = null;
    }
    xhr = null;
  };
  xhr.send();
}
```

な感じで、画像のバイナリをダウンロードして表示させたことはあります。